# Xamarin Forms: How to get the BindableProperty by the property name?

Tags: xamarin, properties, bindable

> Hi, i need to get the BindableProperty by the property name.
>   [image]

```
public BindableProperty GetBindableProperty(BindableObject bindableObj, string propertyName) {
    if(typeof(Entry) == bindableObj.GetType()) {
        if("Text" == propertyName) {
            return (Entry.TextProperty);
        }
        if("TextColor" == propertyName) {
            return (Entry.TextColorProperty);
        }
    }
    return (null);
}
```

> But i do not want to use this "if else" style. 
>   Is there a general way that I don't need to judge the type and name?

Comment: What do you mean by getting a BindableProperty? You have an object and you want to get its bindable property in a generic way?

Comment: yes, i need the object of BindableProperty, in Entry they are static and readonly.

Comment: So they must be public static read-only, i.e. directly Accessible like `Entry.TextProperty` for instance! I mean I do not understand what exactly are you even doing here!

Comment: yes, normally we use it directly. Actually i don't know what are the property name and the BindableObject when i am programming. I need to get it dynamically.

Comment: I am not sure how will that work because if you do not know the property name and value how will you create the BindableProperties on Runtime? Are you trying to show a Dictionary of Data or an ExpandoObject? I mean if you want all this dynamic i am not sure if its possible!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Hi, I found the solution now:

```
public BindableProperty GetBindableProperty(BindableObject bindableObj, string propertyName) {
    Type type = bindableObj.GetType();
    FieldInfo fieldInfo;
    while(null == (fieldInfo = type.GetField(propertyName + "Property", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public))) {
        type = type.BaseType;
    }
    if(null == fieldInfo) {
        throw (new Exception("Can not find the BindableProperty for " + propertyName));
    }
    return ((BindableProperty)(fieldInfo.GetValue(bindableObj)));
}
```